# Does any of the libretto for Gilbert & Sullivan's "magic lozenge" operetta still exist?

Tags: gilbert-and-sullivan

Before he started work on *The Mikado*, W. S. Gilbert had begun the libretto for another operetta, which was never completed.  Their producer, Richard D'Oyly Carte, was pressuring Gilbert and his creative partner, composer Arthur Sullivan, to get another operetta ready, following a disappointingly short run at the Savoy Theatre of their previous collaboration, *Princess Ida*.  Gilbert started working on a fantasy plot, but Sullivan was growing tired of writing comic operas (and supposedly especially tired of comic operas with fantastical plots, like their earlier hit *The Sorcerer*), and he supposedly did not care at all for the book Gilbert was preparing.  Eventually, Gilbert's first idea was abandoned, and the pair ended up creating their best known operetta, *The Mikado*.

What I am wondering is whether anything survives of Gilbert's work on the libretto.  Wikipedia describes the plot of the incomplete operetta as one "in which people fall in love against their wills after taking a magic lozenge."  This sounds like the setup for something somewhat along the lines of *A Midsummer Night's Dream*, but I have never seen any further detail about what was planned (and how much was completed) before the project was canceled.

Comment: I'm flagging this question for Lord High Executioner  attention.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, it became a comic opera, written in collaboration with composer Alfred Cellier, and then after he died, with Ivan Caryll, [*The Mountebanks*](https://hrgsp.org/2019/04/19/a-magic-lozenge/).

[A little more here](https://gsarchive.net/gilbert/plays/mountebanks/mountebanks_home.html), noting the connexion with the "notorious lozenge plot". In this offering, a magic potion transforms the imbiber into whoever they want to be. [Mad-cap menacechmian mayhem ensues](https://gsarchive.net/gilbert/interviews/pall_mall.html), with everyone turning into someone else, until, at the end, order is restored to normal.

Comment: I think the version with a magic potion that lets the drinker change form is how Gilbert's incomplete libretto is portrayed in the movie *Topsy-Turvy*.